# Time not getting converted into unix time properly

Tags: java, android, unix, time

I am trying to retrieve a bunch of values from my database based on values between time1 and time2. So for that I am passing time1 as a paramater (in unix time) and then calculating time2 by extracting the dd-MM-yyyy and adding that to 00:01. Essentially it is, time1-(12AM from time1). For some reason, the conversion from my date format to unix time isn't coming out right. Here's my code:

```
public Cursor getValue(long time) throws ParseException {   // Code to retrieve values steps for every 1 hour
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cu;
    String time_current = String.valueOf(time);
   Log.d("Current Time",String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd        HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(time)));

    String time_past =  String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd ", Locale.getDefault()).format(time)) + "00:01:00.000";
    Log.d("Past time", time_past);
    Date date= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.getDefault()).parse(time_past);

    Log.d("Time passed in time format", String.valueof(date.getTime());
    cu = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from steps_table where time_steps between " + String.valueOf(date.getTime()) + " and " + (time_current)+";", null);
    return cu;
}
```

The log for "time passed in time format" is displaying 1461781860000. Whereas 2016-04-28 12:01 should be 1461801660

Comment: `1461801660` looks like seconds to me.

Comment: Yes, so I corrected my code to save System.currentTimeinMillis()/1000

Comment: Now it shows my "current time" as 1970-01-18 03:34 when I pass System.currentTimeinMillis()/1000 . My time zone is IST. I would assume "String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(time))" is wrong since this is doing the conversion.

Comment: yes Date expects milliseconds not seconds.

Comment: Okay, even if I correct it the other way around. My error still persists.